Swiper.js autoplay issue
I am trying to implement swiper.js into my webflow solution and I have run into a problem. The slider is doing nearly everything I need it to, except for pausing on autoplay when I mouseover the slider. I am a bit new to JS so I am sure I could set up my code better, but here we are.
Any tips and help is helpful!
Here is my read only: https://preview.webflow.com/preview/behold-069ee2?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=behold-069ee2&preview=91156b2bd8815bd6ce3dfe7b4dc6b158&pageId=6656f3fd2e5ecbb745d2e799&locale=en&workflow=preview
this is my JS:
<style>
.slider-list{
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear !important;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear !important;
  transition-timing-function: linear !important;
}
</style>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://weblocks.io/library.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
      var slider_wrapper = new Swiper(".slider-wrapper", {
          wrapperClass: "slider-list",
            slideClass: "slider-item",
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.next-slide',
        prevEl: '.prev-slide',
      },
            
    pagination: {
          type: 'bullets',
      el: '.pagination',
      clickable: true,
      },


 autoplay: {
        delay: 0,
        disableOnInteraction: false, 
        grabCursor: true,
        
},
  speed: 7500,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  loop: true,
  delay: 0,
    });
      });
 
</script>

I have tried to use the swiper.js documentation and implemented the pauseOnMouseEnter=true, but that is so far not working.
I have also tried to set up a mouse event, but since I am such a noob I might have done it wrong and this didnt work either.

Sometimes pauseOnMouseEnter makes problems, depending on version or additional features. Instead this, better when you use classical listeners on mouseEnter and mouseLeave.
Update: now should immediately stop on mouseEnter.
jQuery
$(document).ready(function () {
  const slider_wrapper = new Swiper(".slider-wrapper", {
    wrapperClass: "slider-list",
    slideClass: "slider-item",
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.next-slide',
      prevEl: '.prev-slide',
    },
    pagination: {
      type: 'bullets',
      el: '.pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
    autoplay: {
      delay: 0,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    speed: 7500,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    loop: true,
  });

  $('.slider-wrapper').on('mouseenter', function () {
    slider_wrapper.params.speed = 0;
    slider_wrapper.autoplay.stop();
    slider_wrapper.params.speed = 7500;
  });

  $('.slider-wrapper').on('mouseleave', function () {
    slider_wrapper.autoplay.start();
  });
});

Vanilla
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const slider_wrapper = new Swiper(".slider-wrapper", {
    wrapperClass: "slider-list",
    slideClass: "slider-item",
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.next-slide',
      prevEl: '.prev-slide',
    },
    pagination: {
      type: 'bullets',
      el: '.pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
    autoplay: {
      delay: 0,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    speed: 7500,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    loop: true,
  });

  const sliderElement = document.querySelector('.slider-wrapper');

  sliderElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
    slider_wrapper.params.speed = 0;
    slider_wrapper.autoplay.stop();
    slider_wrapper.params.speed = 7500;
  });

  sliderElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
    slider_wrapper.autoplay.start();
  });
});


Thank you so much for your response! I implemented your code and now it does pause on mouse enter, however it takes almost ten seconds for the slider to actually pause. For mouse leave it starts up again immediately..
here is the most recent link: https://behold-069ee2.webflow.io/
Really appreciate the help, thank you!

Thank you again, but still nothing unfortunately!

Thank you again, but still no change! The only time I have seen it work as an immediate pause on mouse enter was a point way back when the speed was on around 3000 and the delay was on 7500, but it created chaos otherwise. I am wondering if it is something with the swiper.js documentation that I am just not getting

That is odd… Did you try this:  https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-reverse-autoplay-tykdpq?file=%2Findex.html%3A66%2C26
